# Is there a way to know how many ticks/cycles are needed to execute a command?

Tags: linux, command-line, kernel

Is there a way to know how many ticks/cycles are needed to execute a given command on Linux server?

I am trying to execute a command and I want to know the rate of speed at which that command is being executed. Does this time depend on CPU speed or hardware or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `time` command. In its simplest form:

```
time [some command]
```

gives:

```
real    0m0.103s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.028s
```

You can also have a more complete output:

```
/usr/bin/time -v [some command]

Command exited with non-zero status 1                                                                                                     
        Command being timed: "find ."                                                                                                     
        User time (seconds): 0.00                                                                                                         
        System time (seconds): 0.01                                                                                                       
        Percent of CPU this job got: 84%                                                                                                  
        Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.01                                                                              
        Average shared text size (kbytes): 0                                                                                              
        Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0                                                                                            
        Average stack size (kbytes): 0                                                                                                    
        Average total size (kbytes): 0                                                                                                    
        Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 2980
        Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
        Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
        Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 142
        Voluntary context switches: 11
        Involuntary context switches: 0
        Swaps: 0
        File system inputs: 80
        File system outputs: 0
        Socket messages sent: 0
        Socket messages received: 0
        Signals delivered: 0
        Page size (bytes): 4096
        Exit status: 1
```

(when using bash, you have to use the full path to avoid running the buil-in `time` command)

About every item in the output has an influence on the execution time.